# Why is vivado so wasteful with its D-flipflop placement?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, vivado

I have an implemented project in vivado, and I'm looking at the resultant layout between 8 slices:
[image]

As you can see, all 8 slices except one only have a single D-flipflop. This seems awfully wasteful. Why not put all of these flip-flops on two slices?

Comment: In what sense is this "wasteful"? Unless and until you have some use for those other flip-flops, Vivado is going to optimize other aspects of the implementation, such as performance.

Comment: @DaveTweed it seems like there is no loss for the gain of a lot of space. You seem to be seeing something that I am not.

Comment: You have 55 unused FFs in your chip. Why do you care *which* 55 FFs are unused? You haven't shown us your actual design, so it's difficult to be specific. For example, if most of your FFs connect to I/O pins, then spreading them out in this way makes those connections more evenly matched, which is a huge win for performance.

Comment: I think what you want or expected is that the tool would be economic with the space, so you could get an idea how much of your chip is used by looking at the used / unused areas. But that is not how these tools work: they have fixed resources to work with, and saving any of them is not a goal, as long as none of the recources is exceeded.

Comment: Things that are clustered, and clumped and look pretty to the human eye aren't necessarily what runs best or easiest to work with. A massive PCB with lots of empty space and layers is easier to route and perhaps wasteful...but if it's already there then why not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Has the placer violated space constraints? No.

Has the router violated timings constraints? Probably not, if it finished successfully.

In which case you have a good design.

If you reduced the size of chip available to it, you'd find it would put more latches per slice.

If you tightened the timing constraints, you might find that if local routing resources were faster than inter-slice, that it would place latches on the same slice.

Lots of things have to be optimised by a placer/router. Amongst them is fast access to I/O pins, and heat generation, both of which would favour a spread such as you've shown.

Unless you've had several iterations around the constraints, you're not going to get the fastest possible, or the tightest area layout. When it's met constraints, the placer/router usually stops.

It's not obvious when we first write constraints for an automatic tool just how it's going to satisfy those. I frequently find myself thinking 'Oh, I didn't mean that, but I suppose that's exactly what I asked for' when doing this sort of thing.

There's a quite fun AI example where the system is given a bipedal walker, and asked to optimise its speed from start point to finish point across some difficult terrain. One solution it came up with was to give the walker very long legs, and have it fall over at the start. It was so tall it reached the finish.

Consider another optimisation problem. Manufacturer A wants to optimise his tools, so that me, the user, chooses them over manufacturer B. What makes a good placer/router, once meeting constraints has been achieved? A FAST placer router wins. If I use 90% of the resources, then I expect the tool to struggle, but if use 10%, I expect it to fly through. Why would the tool designers have it put all the latches in one slice, and then struggle to optimise the constrained local routing, when this initial placement is guarranteed to route easily?

Answer (score 2):

If your complaint is about how Vivado doesn’t pack flipflops into CLBs, your criticism is misplaced. Vivado will work as hard *as it has to to* place your design. In this case the tool chose to space out the flip flops rather than pack them probably because the design routed easier, and, your design isn’t very dense.

So Vivado didn’t work very hard. Did your design fit? Did it close timing? Then, mission accomplished. If your design were more dense then it might resort to tighter packing.

I’ve placed and routed designs that used close to 90% of the CLBs in a device, and closed timing. But I had to work for it, carefully isolating timing regions with slices, FIFOs and other techniques.

Don’t snatch defeat from the jaws of victory!

Answer (score 1):

It could be any of hundreds of reasons. It might improve timing, they might have different async resets, it might be a random artifact of the placement process, etc.

If it's causing you a specific problem, you should find a way to constrain your design to avoid that.